# Filtering of dictionary of array from dictionary value

Tags: arrays, swift, filter

I am finding difficulties in filtering dictionaries in the array. Please check my response below.

```
[{
       id = 5a5dae2cb9f9e54a56987185;
       addressId = 0;
       claimStatus = PENDING;
       claimStatusChangedOn = 0;
       gift =         {
           giftAmount = 50;
           giftAmountFormated = "\U20b9 50.00";
           productId = 1

       }
},
{
       id = 5a5dae2cb9f9e54a56987185;
       addressId = 0;
       claimStatus = PENDING;
       claimStatusChangedOn = 0;
       gift =         {
           giftAmount = 50;
           giftAmountFormated = "\U20b9 50.00";
           productId = 2

       }
},
{
       id = 5a5dae2cb9f9e54a56987185;
       addressId = 0;
       claimStatus = PENDING;
       claimStatusChangedOn = 0;
       gift =         {
           giftAmount = 50;
           giftAmountFormated = "\U20b9 50.00";
           productId = 3

       }
},
{
       id = 5a5dae2cb9f9e54a56987185;
       addressId = 0;
       claimStatus = PENDING;
       claimStatusChangedOn = 0;
       gift =         {
           giftAmount = 50;
           giftAmountFormated = "\U20b9 50.00";
           productId = 1

       }
},
{
       id = 5a5dae2cb9f9e54a56987185;
       addressId = 0;
       claimStatus = PENDING;
       claimStatusChangedOn = 0;
       gift =         {
           giftAmount = 50;
           giftAmountFormated = "\U20b9 50.00";
           productId = 1
       }
}]
```

I want different array filtered by `gifts -> productId`.

for example, array1 will be dictionaries with productId = 1,
array2 will be having the dictionaries with productId =2
etc.

I couldn't understand reduce, filter and map deeply.

Comment: How can we help you? I don't see a problem or a question. please show some code, explain what is wrong with it and we will try to help

Answer (score 0):

I just got it.Sorry my question was not clear. I wanted to group the array by productId in gifts dictionary.

This is what I found :

```
let groupDict = Dictionary(grouping:array){ (dictionaryObj) -> String in
    return dictionaryObj.gift.productId
}
```